# How to deal with the tailing padding between ctypes and cython?

Tags: structure, padding, cython, ctypes, tail

The struct defined in a third-party c++ library is:

```
struct CSomeStruct {
    double a;
    char b;
    int c;
}
```

The same structure defined in my cython project using ctypes is:

```
class PSomeStructParent(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('a', c_double),
        ('b', c_char)
    ]
class PSomeStruct(PSomeStructParent):
    _fields_ = [
        ('c', c_int)
    ]
```

Why I use inheritance is because there are many similar structures which have the same common fields(100 or more). But the c++ library defined them in respective structs. C++ and ctypes have the same default pack padding 8. So if I transfer these structures between c++ and cython, the memory buffer is different and can't be cast correctly.

```
sizeof(CStruct) = sizeof(double)+sizeof(char)+3+sizeof(int) = 8+1+3+4 = 16
sizeof(PStruct) = sizeof(c_double)+sizeof(c_char)+7+sizeof(int)+4 = 8+1+7+4+4=24
```

Is there any method to deal with ctypes tailing padding and can be tranfered for the third-party library? I can't stand to define so many fields repeatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shared_fields = [
    ('a', ctypes.c_double),
    ('b', ctypes.c_char)
]

class PSomeStruct(ctypes.Structure):
  _fields_ = shared_fields + [('c',ctypes.c_int)]
```

Give that the fields are defined by a list you can just use Python to build the list you need, minimising duplication.